# Avoid multiples queries on serializer with `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` in a `ListField`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following serializer

```py
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    fields = serializers.ListField(
        allow_empty=False,
        child=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=someModel.objects.all())
    )
```

When I run the following code on my view/code:

```py
serializer = SomeSerializer(data={'fields': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
serializer.is_valid()
```

4 different queries are run against the DB, one `get(id)` for each `someModel`. Is there any way to ask the serializer to perform just one query?, that way the serializer uses something like:

```py
queryset.filter(pk__in=[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

instead of:

```py
queryset.get(1)
queryset.get(2)
queryset.get(3)
queryset.get(4)
```

I tried digging on the [django-rest-framework source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/df92e57ad6c8394ca54654dfc7a2722f822ed8c8/rest_framework/relations.py#L264) and it looks like it only performs `get` in order to get the data of each model. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Related docs: 1) [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and 2) [Serializer relations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) (ctrl-f "does not attempt")

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for your comment, I don know prefetch and select related, but I don't know how to rewrite my serializer in order to get that optimization query.

From my understanding, the issue is not with the queryset, but with the ListField that ask for the value of each `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` individually.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the rest framework library, you'd have to rewrite how it is handled to address the problem properly. I've documented my finding here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/discussions/8919

The simplest thing you can do is limit the queryset to only the primary key: `queryset=someModel.objects.only("pk")` It won't remove the n+1 problem, but it will make it faster to query since you're not querying unneeded fields.